# What is the relationship between data structures and algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I have been searching for a good online course in data structures but have found that Google also returns results for algorithms courses, which say stuff like:

> In this course you will learn several fundamental principles of
>   algorithm design: divide-and-conquer methods, graph algorithms,
>   **practical data structures (heaps, hash tables, search trees)**,
>   randomized algorithms, and more. [[source]](https://www.coursera.org/course/algo)

and

> By the end of this class you will understand key concepts needed to
>   devise new algorithms for graphs **and other important data structures**
>   and to evaluate the efficiency of these algorithms. [[source]](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs215)

and

> This course provides an introduction to mathematical modeling of
>   computational problems. It covers the common algorithms, algorithmic
>   paradigms, **and data structures used to solve these problems**. [[source]](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/)

My question is: are algorithms and data structures intimately linked, meaning that they must be understood together or is one topic more foundational than the other?

*EDIT: For those voting to close this question, can you please tell me why and maybe how to improve this one? Learning to ask the right questions is part of the educational process.*

Comment: A data structure is static, and can do nothing. An algorithm is just a set of instructions to perform on some data. Without one, the other is useless. Together, they make computer programs. They're both fundamental.

Comment: @Phoshi Wrong. Data structure are closely tied to algorithms that manipulate the data. So closely tied those algorithms are considered part of the data structure. For example Lined List data structure tells you how the data is saved and also how the data is read and manipulated.

Comment: per my reading, this question pretty much falls into issues covered in [Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog). It's not reasonable to expect of site audience to read mind of those who advertized these courses, and answer are going to be merely opinionated guesses

Comment: @Euphoric I'd argue it's wrong to say that algorithms are part of the data structure. There's more than one way to implement a binary search: you can, for example, do the naive `if less than recurse to the left; if greater than, recurse to the right; if equal, return` search or the slightly more sophisticated `if less than recurse to the left; otherwise keep track of this value as a potential candidate and recurse to the right; check for equality once we reach the leaves`. They have slightly different numbers of comparisons. Both are one of the many things you could choose to do with a tree.

Comment: @Doval I didn't say all algorithms are part of data structure. I'm saying data structure is not just structure of data itself, but also algorithms that operate on this data. You can have same kind of data (linked list-like), but you can have linked list, queue or stack depending on what algorithms the structure uses.

Comment: @Euphoric: I disagree. A "linked list" is just how the data is laid out in memory, in cells of `(data, next)` (in the trivial case). You have *separate* algorithms for linked list traversal, which use general techniques for traversing some data structure. Consider that you can view a linked list as a flat directed graph, or a particularly wonky tree, without having to come up with entirely new classes of algorithm.

Comment: @Euphoric You're confusing the data structure with the abstract data type that the combination of data structure and algorithms implement.

Comment: @gnat, that makes sense. The reason I quoted from several sources was to show that I didn't think it was just one person's (blog's) opinion but rather a pattern I saw. My only thought about fixing this question per your suggestion is to not quote from the courses but ask the question directly. I'm not sure that adds value per se.

Comment: @Doval But from context of question, we can assume the person asking assumes data structure = abstract data type. We can even say that is root of his confusion and inability to find any relevant source.

Comment: @Euphoric, I have to disagree. merge sort is an algorithm. An array is a data structure. A linked list is a different data structure. I can write an implementation of MergeSort to operate on either. Some data structures may be more natural or more efficient for a particular algorithm, but it is rarely an absolute requirement (you do pretty much have to have a heap to implement heap sort). Nicholas Wirth wrote a popular text book in the 1980s titled: "Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs"

Comment: I think the title of Wirth's book sums it up fairly well "Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs" (http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Structures-Prentice-Hall-Automatic-Computation/dp/0130224189)

Comment: This question, regardless of the title, reads as advice on what course to take. It also comes across as primarily opinion-based. It's not a good fit as it stands.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All sorts of mixtures do exist. You have data structures, which are not associated with algorithms, algorithms, which require no (real) data structures, but most often the two come in one package.

*Edit:* as @Doval correctly pointed out, data structures per se do not have any operations associated with them. The act of combining data structure and algorithm forms an abstract data type.

## Data structures without algorithms

Consider for example a data structure for storing 2-dimensional coordinates, appropriately called `Point`. There is nothing much in terms of algorithms to be done for a point and it really is just a container for an `x` and `y` value. Of course, giving this data structure, you can now add all sorts of algorithms on top of it (distance calculation, convex hulls, what-have-you).

You can think of a lot of data structures, which are simply an accumulation of individual data. While these do occur frequently in practice, they do not make for good teaching material, because there is nothing to be learned from it, once you have understood, that single data items can be accumulated into a new data structure (like what do you learn after the above `Point` example, if I provide you with that awesome data structure called `Point3D`, which can do the same thing for 3-dimensional space?)

## Algorithms without (real) data structures

"Real", because obviously every interesting algorithm needs primitive data types like integers or booleans, and we do not want to consider those as data structures in this context. Similarly to above, these algorithms are typically rather simple ones. In particular, they do not come with a complicated state of any sort, because that usually goes into a data structure (see next section).

An example for such an algorithm would be calculating the greatest common divisor of two numbers. Euklid's algorithms for the gcd really only needs to hold two integers and manipulates them.

Once things start to get more interesting, you very soon enter the world of abstract data types though. For example, the sieve of Eratosthenes is based on an array. We could have a discussion now, whether an array is still primitive, or in fact, you could discuss if an integer isn't already a data structure. Either way, algorithms that exist completely without data structures are rather boring, even if you accept their isolated existence.

## Algorithms combined with data structures, aka abstract data types

Now these are the interesting ones, but for two very different reasons. Typically, you can approach these from two directions: data structure first, or algorithm first.

While an abstract data type is defined by the combination of data structure + algorithms/operations, we often view them with a focus on either one of those and consider the other one as enablers.

### Data structure, then algorithm

You will encounter abstract data types, which are rather simple to use, but involve more or less complicated algorithms to make them work internally. For example, a `HashMap` is trivial to use, but involves a nifty hash function and dealing with the hash collisions on the inside. Yet, from your point of view as a user you care about it as something that holds data for you, not something that does something for you.

In contrast to the last group below, these data structures do not expose their users to these algorithms. You do not need to know, nor care, about a `HashMap`s internal hash function in order to be able to use it. (To use it effectively though, you may want to know these things ;)

### Algorithm, then data structure

The other direction means you have an algorithm, which you want to be able to simply use, but which needs data structures internally to make it work as intended. An example would be a binary space partitioning (BSP) algorithm, that you can simply ask for the 2-dimensional `Point` from a large set of points that is closest to a given query point. However, you need a tree structure (and even additional algorithms like distance calculations) on the inside to actually write the algorithm.

In general, one can say that algorithms in this group use involved data structures for their internal state representation. I would argue, that this group of algorithms is the most diverse and you will find many many different ones that fit this general scheme. Regarding the point of view, we see these as interesting, because they do something (f.ex. sorting) for us, and do not care as much about the data holding part.

### Closely related data structures and algorithms

Finally, you have data structures, which are very close related to algorithms that directly correspond with them. A typical example is a binary tree, which, when you want to do anything meaningful with it, forces the topic of tree-walking algorithms on you (depth-first, breadth-first, whatever).

For these cases, we change the focus of our view of the resulting abstract data types every so often. Sometimes you care about the structure of your tree, a few minutes later you care about being able to run a find operation on it, then you wonder about deleting a node, and right-away about how the structure looks afterwards. While all of this holds true for the other sections above as well, it is not something that is the primary focus in your mind, for example, when you store/retrieve data to/from a `Map`, or when you sort a linked list.

Comment: You're conflating data structures and abstract data types. A data structure *doesn't do anything*. It makes no sense to say "you will encounter data structures, which are rather simple to use" because a data structure is just a structure. A `Map` is an abstract data type that may be implemented using a particular data structure and a set of algorithms that produce the desired results by traversing and manipulating the structure. The data structure doesn't hide the algorithms, because it has none; the abstract data type hides the data structure (that's what makes it abstract.)

Comment: Note that in a sense algorithms are always hidden because there's no way to inspect functions. That's probably why they're called *abstractions* in lambda calculus (whose only data type is functions).

Comment: You are correct. Nevertheless, I see a distinction between how we view the different ADTs. I have edited my answer and hope it is clearer now and no longer conflates the structure with ADTs, while still emphasizing, that you can focus on structure and/or operations for any ADT.

Comment: Is it really too simple to say that data structures are nouns and algorithms are verbs? I suppose you might say that the algorithm is the implementation of the verb, but you still **search** a **tree**, even if that search is a binary search. You'd miss out on all the technical detail by saying so, but it does have a certain elegance.

Comment: @Doval: Even if a data structure which simply consists of a bunch of numbers in an array which are required to have and maintain some relationship to each other, such a thing may be "easy to use" if it's easy to maintain the required invariants while doing what one wants, or "hard to use" if it is difficult.

Comment: @supercat Wouldn't it be the algorithm that's easy?

Comment: @Doval: Not necessarily, particularly if there are many valid arrangements of numbers in the array.  Consider, for example, a variable-length array `a` whose present length is `n` and has the requirement that if `i` < `n/2`, then `a[i] < a[i*2]` and (unless i=(n-1)/2) `a[i] < a[i*2+1]`.  An array which is organized in such fashion might reasonably be considered a "data structure" but it can't really "do" anything.  On the other hand, if you were given the task of removing the fifty smallest numbers in that array, while leaving its invariant intact...

Comment: ...that could be accomplished much more efficiently than if the array was unsorted (note that if the array has 1,000,000,000 elements, any one of them might be the 50th smallest, but it would be possible to pull out the 50 smallest elements while looking at only a tiny fraction of the elements in the array.

Comment: @supercat On the other hand there's other tasks that are hard to do with that array. "Easy to use" is very vaguely defined for a data structure, because the "easy" part depends on what you're trying to do, and there's an infinite number of things you might want to do. Even when it's well-defined, it's not the same notion of ease Frank was using, which is that you don't need to know the algorithm a `Map` uses to use a `Map`.

Comment: @Doval: For any kind of thing, the phrase "Easy to use" is relative to some intended usage.  Saying a can opener is easy to use would imply that opening cans with the aid of the device is easy.  It would not imply that there are not other tasks which would be possible but difficult using just a can-opener, but perhaps much easier with a more suitable tool.  My main point was that something like a general-purpose array in combination with a stated invariant can be a "data structure", even if there's no specific chunk of code associated with the invariant.

Answer (score 5):

Data structures often influence the details of an algorithm. Because of this the two often go hand in hand.

Consider for example an algorithm for cutting your lawn. How you go about cutting your lawn is likely to be influenced by the actual structure of your lawn. If you live in a small house in a densely packed suburb and your lawn is just a small rectangle a few meters squared in area, you would probably prefer to cut your lawn with a push-mower instead of a tractor/riding mower. If your lawn involves many acres of flat meadow land, your preference may be for the riding mower as opposed to the push-mower (though either mower may eventually get the job done). If your lawn involves acres of land with large flat areas, but a few small hills and a number of trees, you may develop a more interesting algorithm for cutting the lawn that involves both a riding mower and a push-mower, or some other grass cutting techniques.

Ultimately though, the structure of your data may have a significant impact on your decisions for how to develop your algorithm (or which algorithms to use). For this reason, the two topics often go hand in hand.

And vice versa: sometimes the algorithm we want to use influences (at least at the onset of computing) the data structures you develop to support the algorithm. For example going from an array list to the idea of a linked list and eventually to a BST for storing an ordered list that will allow for quick find.